# Spring Kafka with SSL on Azure

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using
sppring-Kafka 2.1.2

deployed into azure app service

using file system - blob storage

countered the following problems. and I am a little lost between sources.

01- in the application.yml when provide the kesytore.p12/truststor.p12 location using the classpath: it never works unless it's an external file system location.

02- tried to find a way to use ssl bundles with kafka but could not find how to do it.

03- ssl configurations for kafka is separate from ones used with schema registry.

is there an easy way to refer to these files/bundles and just use them with kafka, and schema registry at the same time?

I tried to serve the keystore and truststore from external file system and it worked ...